# Indoor navigation using JOSM

Tags: android, navigation, coordinates

currently I'm doing my Final Year Project regarding indoor navigation. I have the blueprint of my map but how do i edit it n plot the coordinates in JOSM. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the file format of your blueprint, you may want to give a try to the following JOSM plugins:

- [ImportImage plugin](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/ImportImagePlugin)
- [ImageWayPoint plugin](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/ImageWayPoint)
- [PicLayer plugin](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/PicLayer)

They allow you to display a picture (geottaged or not) as imagery background to trace data from it.